# phpQuery namespace

Tags: php, namespace

Всем привет. Столкнулся с проблемой подключения phpQuery в проекте который использует namespace php. Если кто-то решал эту проблему подскажите плиз как это более менее быстро решить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
  require ('phpQuery/phpQuery.php');

  $content = file_get_contents('http://example.com');
  $document = \phpQuery::newDocument($content);

  $hentry = $document->find('div.class');

  foreach ($hentry as $el) {...}
```

Все классы, у которых не указано пространство имен, находятся в корне. т.е. и обращаться к ним нужно так: \phpQuery::newDocument($content);
Либо, в начале файла достаточно указать use. Получится что-то вроде этого:

```
<?php
use \phpQuery;
// ну и обращаемся к нему напрямую
$document = phpQuery::newDocument($content);
```

Comment: Я не стой стороны зашел :). Спасибо что расклинивали.